# Showing automorphism group is trivial

Tags: galois-theory

Let $f(x) \in k[x]$ be a separable polynomial of degree $n\geq 3 $ with Galois group isomorphic to $S_n$, and let $\alpha \in \bar{k}$ be a root of $f(x)$.

a) Show f is irreducible (I have already shown this)

b) Show $Aut_k(k(\alpha)) = \{id\}$

I am not sure how to do (b).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to show that $\textrm{Aut}_k(k(\alpha))$ is trivial, it suffices to show that the only root of $f(x)$ in $k(\alpha)$ is $\alpha.$

Suppose to the contrary that there is some root $\beta \in k(\alpha)$ with $\beta \neq \alpha$. Then in $k(\alpha)[x]$, we have
$$f(x) = (x - \alpha)(x - \beta)g(x),$$
where $g(x)$ has degree $n - 2$. Let $L$ be the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $k$. Since the Galois group of $f(x)$ is $S_n$, we must have $[L : k] = n!$. By the above factorization, $[L : k(\alpha)] \leq (n - 2)!$. Since $f(x)$ is irreducible, we also have $[k(\alpha) : k] = n$. But then
$$[L : k] = [L : k(\alpha)][k(\alpha) : k] \leq (n - 2)! \cdot n < n!,$$
a contradiction. Here we use $n \geq 3$ to conclude the last inequality above.